# How can I put a function the FileName parameter of a File...SaveAs?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a file using VBA, name the file and embed a date into the filename. In Mac Excel 2011, if "wb" were the reference for the newly created workbook, it would have been no problem to say...

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="Old_New_Cust" & Cstr(Date) & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
```

In Excel 2016 and El Capitan, this particular line gives an error saying the file has been saved as a 9-digit number which I can never find.

Whenever I use the FileFormat parameter, this results in an error so I dropped it for experimentation purposes. I have tried putting the entire filename (including the date) into a string variable and running...
wb.SaveAs Filename:=xxx, := FileFormat:=52 with xxx being the unquoted variable name referring to the filename. This interprets the variable name as a literal.

The same result with "\FileNameString", "$FileNameString", "FileNameString", "/$FileNameString", `Application.Evaluate(FileNameString)`, [FileNameString]. Either I get an error message stating the file can't be saved, the file is saved as a nine-digit integer, or the VBA won't execute the line.

The only way I can get this to work is to use a literal for the file name without trying to execute any functions such as "Date" or "Cstr(Date)" in the line. Does anybody know how to either execute a function (like we used to be able to) or get a string from a variable name while using the FileName parameter?

Comment: workbook.saveas strFileName, xlFileFormat.xlExcel.....

Comment: I suspect the problem is the data format. Try: `wb.SaveAs Filename:="Old_New_Cust" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"` for example.

Comment: Rory, thanks for the quick response. That worked great. Thanks for the solution. I'm sorry I haven't had a chance to try the other idea submitted by creddit but I will try it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I use,

```
Sub G5()
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\ME\Documents\Testing\" & _
               Range("G5") & "\" & theMonth & "\" 'change this path to whatever destination you want the files saved to
filename = Range("G5")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & "-" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```